# Formatar saída do json separando em vírgulas

Tags: javascript

Tenho uma objeto `json` e quero dividir em vírgulas o resultado. ***Exemplo***: `01`,`02`,`03`,`04`,`05`

***Objeto*** `json`:

```
[{"rank":"0102030405"}]
```

Script de saída HTML

```
$.each(data, function() {
    $('div#content').append(this.rank);
});
```

Comment: Segue algum padrão de tamanho? sempre vai ser de dois em dois caracteres? o que o correr apos rank 99?

Comment: O objeto sempre vem com essa quantidade de números. Ou Seja cinco dezenas.

Comment: Na minha humilde opnião, isso já começou errado. Se possível, tente alterar a forma que estes dados estão sendo enviados.

Comment: Não seria o caso de trabalhar o seu back-end para devolver um `"rank": [01, 02, ... ]`? A não ser que tenha um padrão (como mencionado pelo Guilherme).

Comment: Poderia trabalhar o back mais queira ver a solução no Js

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sim, é possível via RegEx:

```js
console.log("0102030405".match(/.{1,2}/g));
```

Irá gerar a seguinte saída:

```
[
  "01",
  "02",
  "03",
  "04",
  "05"
]
```

O parâmetro `{1,N}` especifica captura de grupos de tamanho `N`.

Você pode então concatenar os resultados via `.join()`:

```js
    console.log("0102030405".match(/.{1,2}/g).join(','));
```

O resultado será:

```
01,02,03,04,05
```

Porém, como comentado, seria interessante que você tivesse esse valor gerado no seu backend se possível.

Comment: Bingo, @OnoSendai